# Is it possible to add instance methods to all "classes" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is more of an exploratory question, seeing how the core JavaScript stuff works.  I realize the convention is to not override any core JavaScript classes, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

You can create what acts like "class methods" in JavaScript by adding to the core `Function` prototype like this:

```
Function.prototype.class_method = function() {
  console.log("class method called")
}

var User;
User = (function() {
  function User() {}
  return User;
})();

User.class_method(); // "class method called"
```

My question is, is there a way to add "instance methods" in a similar way?  Something crazy like this, but what's below doesn't work (or make any sense):

```
alias = Function.prototype.constructor;
Function.prototype.constructor = function() {
  child = this;
  child.prototype.instance_method = function() {
    console.log("instance method called");
  }
  alias.apply(child);
}

var user = new User();
user.instance_method(); // method doesn't exist
```

It's almost like you'd need to override the `Function` class' `constructor` method and access the `prototype` from there.  Is this possible?

It does work if you add to the `Object.prototype` like this:

```
Object.prototype.instance_method = function() {
  console.log("instance method");
}

var user = new User();
user.instance_method(); // "instance method called"
```

But that doesn't seem right either, mainly because seeing the output in the node.js console from `console.log({});` change is confusing:

```
console.log({});
// {};

Object.prototype.instance_method = function() {
  console.log("instance method");
}

console.log({});
// {"instance_method": [Function]}
```

Comment: actually you won't call them `classes` they are `constructor functions`. this might help you too https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using node.js, you should be able to use [`Object.defineProperty` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and make the new property *non-enumerable*:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'instance_Method', {
    value: function() {
        console.log("instance method");
    },
    enumerable: false // it's already the default
});
```

This was introduced in ECMAScript5, so only newer browsers will support it.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand when the prototype comes into play. It's simply an object that is a property of a function. It only has meaning when you use the `new` keyword. Example:

```
    var Widget = function(val) {
        this.value = val;
    };
    Widget.prototype.getValue = function() {
        return this.value;
    };
    var widget1 = new Widget('test');
    widget1.getValue();  // test
    var widget2 = new Widget('test2');
    widget2.getValue();  // test2
```

When `new` is used, the js interpreter will create a hidden `_proto_` property on the instance. This proto link is simply a reference to the prototype object of the constructor function, e.g., Widget at the time the constructor was called.

When you override the `Function` constructor, you are literally adding something that will be on the `_proto_` property of every function created after you modified `Function.prototype`.

If you make the statement `child.prototype... = ...` in your base 'class' constructor function, then that prototype will not have meaning until something 'instantiates' child, e.g., `var child = new child();`.

A great [Resource](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141).

To answer your question about 'instance methods', you simply need to do something like the following:

```
    var Widget = function() {
        this.method = function() {
            return 'instance method';
        };
    };
    Widget.prototype.method = function() {
        return 'class method';
    };
    var widget1 = new Widget();
    widget1.method();  // instance method
    delete widget1.method;
    widget1.method();  // class method
```

This is due to javascript's implementation of Prototypical Inheritance. The *proto* link I spoke of before is key here. When `widget1` was first created, inside the constructor function Widget, `method` was attached specifically to widget1. This `method` will not be available to other instances. However, `method` on the prototype is shared across all instances of Widget.

At runtime, when the js interpreter sees `widget1.method();`, it first sees if `widget1` has `method` as a property directly on it (objects in js are just hashmaps in essence, in which the keys are called 'properties'). It finds the instance method as a property in this case. However, once you delete the instance method, it will attempt to follow the `_proto_` link, which is just an object reference to Widget.prototype (at the time the constructor was called). Widget.prototype.method is defined; therefore, the interpreter will execute that. If no `method` function is found when continuing to follow `_proto_` links, it'll be a run-time error.

Comment: Note that the `instanceof` operator does not rely on the `constructor` property, even if you redefine `Function.prototype.constructor` checking `(function(){}) instanceof Function` will return `true`. The `instanceof` operator inspects the internal prototype chain directly, the side effect that you will observe is that all function objects inherit that redefined `constructor` property, e.g. `(function () {}.constructor)`.